# PostgreSQL background process raising errors

Tags: postgresql

At about 7:45 this morning, errors started appearing in our customer's PostgreSQL logs.  Nobody from my company was working on their system at that time.  The error messages have nothing to do with our client's database or the software that we provided.  As far as I can tell, the software we provided is operating normally.

Can anyone tell me what might be happening and how to correct it?

This is an ancient PostgreSQL installation: version 8.1 running on Windows Server 2003.  We've never updated it because it is still working.

```
2019-08-08 07:43:23 FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "application_name"
2019-08-08 07:43:32 FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "application_name"
2019-08-08 07:43:52 FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "application_name"
2019-08-08 07:43:52 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "has_priviledge" at character 90
2019-08-08 07:43:52 STATEMENT:  
  SELECT
      has_table_privilege(
            'pgagent.pga_job', 'INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE'
          ) has_priviledge
      WHERE EXISTS(
          SELECT has_schema_privilege('pgagent', 'USAGE')
          WHERE EXISTS(
              SELECT cl.oid FROM pg_class cl
              LEFT JOIN pg_namespace ns ON ns.oid=relnamespace
              WHERE relname='pga_job' AND nspname='pgagent'
          )
      )

2019-08-08 07:43:53 ERROR:  column "state" does not exist
2019-08-08 07:43:53 STATEMENT:  /*pga4dash*/
      SELECT 'session_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
      FROM (SELECT
         (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity) AS "Total",
         (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active')  AS "Active",
         (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle')  AS "Idle"
      ) t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'tps_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
      FROM (SELECT
         (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Transactions",
         (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Commits",
         (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Rollbacks"
      ) t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ti_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
      FROM (SELECT
         (SELECT sum(tup_inserted) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Inserts",
         (SELECT sum(tup_updated) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Updates",
         (SELECT sum(tup_deleted) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Deletes"
      ) t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'to_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
      FROM (SELECT
         (SELECT sum(tup_fetched) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Fetched",
         (SELECT sum(tup_returned) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Returned"
      ) t
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 'bio_stats' AS chart_name, row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
      FROM (SELECT
         (SELECT sum(blks_read) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Reads",
         (SELECT sum(blks_hit) FROM pg_stat_database) AS "Hits"
      ) t
```

Comment: application_name is a parameter to connect to a postgres server, introduced with version 9.0 (?). so it seems someone updated a tool on that server or connecting to that server, maybe pga4dash, guessing there is 9.0 or newer running ?

Comment: Looks like that query comes from pgAdmin4: https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/REL-4_11/web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/pgagent/tests/utils.py#L49